# Bluetooth SCO to single android application, not to entire android system

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth-sco

I am using following code in my application to use bluetooth headset for audio IN and OUT. It is working fine.

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.startBluetoothSco();
am.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
```

But, When I played song using Music Player app, along with my application also running, the song is coming in bluetooth headset. This is because I  changed the Audio Manager of android system to Bluetooth SCO.

But my requirement is the **audio IN and OUT must work with bluetooth headset to my application only and it should not disturb other apps**, Is it possible ?? or not ??

Please provide your valuable suggestions. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a SCO channel you are essentially adding an audio channel. Think of it like a wired handsfree. When you connect the handsfree all audio is routed to it and not just one specific applications's audio. To use the BT headset only for your app, connect the SCO channel when the app starts and disconnect when the app is exited or goes into background.